# Custom MKAnnotationView masksToBounds=YES and canShowCallout=YES exception

Tags: objective-c, ios6, uiview, mkmapview, mkannotationview

How to I properly set a radius on a custom MKAnnotationView and allow callouts? This throws an exception:

From my custom MKAnnotationView class:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];

    if (self)
    {
        self.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30);
        self.opaque = NO;

        self.multipleTouchEnabled = NO;
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

        self.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
        self.layer.masksToBounds = YES;

        self.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blueColor].CGColor;
        self.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;

        self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(1, 0);
        self.layer.shadowColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
        self.layer.shadowRadius = 5;
        self.layer.shadowOpacity = .25;
    }

    return self;
}
```

Within my class that presents the map view:

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    // logic to dequeue annotation views, etc.

    annotationView.canShowCallout = YES;        
    return annotationView;
}
```

Exceptions:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: '> cannot show callout with clipsToBounds enabled'
>   *** First throw call stack:
>   (0x1c04012 0x1689e7e 0x4eab5f 0x4ebcaf 0x4ebaea 0x4ebf03 0x4d7e24 0x4d7e54 0x4da610 0x5a7e 0x221853f 0x222a014 0x221a7d5 0x1baaaf5 0x1ba9f44 0x1ba9e1b 0x1a617e3 0x1a61668 0x5cdffc 0x29ad 0x28d5)
>   libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
>   (lldb)

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution. I created an OuterAnnotationView with a clear color and added a subview to the OuterAnnotationView on initialization. The subview that I added (the inner) I can set
a cornerRadius and masksToBounds=YES and everything works now.

Comment: Did you have to do anything with the frame size of the outer annotation view to get it to size properly with the subview?

Answer (score 2):

```
-(MKAnnotationView *)annotationView{



    annotationView.image=[UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:profilePictureString]]];
    annotationView.canShowCallout = NO;
    annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeInfoDark];

    annotationView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 50,50);
    annotationView.layer.cornerRadius = 25;
    annotationView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
    annotationView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;


    return annotationView;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, re write it with:

self.layer.masksToBounds = NO;